# why private static methods exists those are not being called in any static context?

Tags: java, arraylist, static, private

Since static things loaded at time of class loading,and can be used even before object creation as `ClassName.member`

but if static method is private,so you can only do this thing `ClassName.method()` inside class which is also accessible by directly `method()` without appending classname.

Hence making a `private` method `static` has no significance untill it is not being used in any `static` method of same class.since only private can not be use in some other static method of same class.

But I seen some method those are not being use in any other static stuff and still they are `static`.For Example `hugeCapacity` method of `ArrayList`-

```
private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {...}
```

**why we not not keep it private only ?**

```
private int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {...}
```

Can one let me know significance behind, making this method static in our java Libraries?

Comment: Since the method is not making use of having access to an instance of its class, there is no need for it to be _not static_.

Comment: @khelwood So your concern is,if any private not intended to be called from instance should be static as well?

Comment: Generally, yes.

Comment: @khelwood  `private` can never be called from `instance`,so every time be must use `private static` than why many only `private` method exists in library?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what `private` means. Private methods can be called from an instance of the class they are declared in.

Comment: The only instance I can think of is when initializing an object using a Lazy.  For example `SomeObject foo = new Lazy<SomeObject>(InitFoo());`  Lazys will lazy load a value until it is use.  They take static method and as Func to create the value.

Comment: Oh, another reason is if you are calling a private static method from a public static method in the same class, here may be use in seperating static tasks in the object for just for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 6):

Making this distinction (that is not mandatory) conveys a meaning for clients of the class and gives hints on their behavior.

```
private int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {...}
```

supposes that the method behavior depends on the current instance.
So the client class expects that it may manipulate instance members and **optionally** static members.

while this

```
private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {...}
```

supposes that the method behavior is a class method that is not related to a specific instance. So it can manipulate **only** static members.

---

It is not a great optimization but it spares an additional parameter that is passed to each method by the JVM.

You don't see it in the source code but for instance methods, `this` is indeed added in the compiled code as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a method which doesn't use the instance, it is clearer and more efficient to make it `static`.

Using a instance method which doesn't actually use `this` can be confusing, and it is potentially more work for the JVM to pass around a reference you don't use.